# Sequelize one-to-one ассоциации Node.js

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, sequelize.js

Есть две таблицы

```
case_open 
    id 
    case_item_id
```

и

```
 item
   id
   name
```

есть связь между ними

```
db.case_open.hasOne(db.item, {as: 'item', foreignKey: 'id', targetKey:'case_item_id'})
```

но при выводе логов получается такое:

```
@db.case_open.findAll
    where:
      'user_item_status' : 3
    include:
      model: @db.item
      as: 'item'
  .then (@itemsToUser) =>

case.id:196
case.case_item_id  488
item.id 196
```

складывается ощущение что связалось case_open.id и item.id только непонятно почему. Код на CoffeeScript